# Why is a node not updated by setting curr pointer?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I am working with code that is to rearrange a linked list, such that nodes are taken from the front and back of the list in alternating fashion, and so convert a list of 1->2->3->4->5->6 to 1->6->2->5->3->4.

This is the code for rearranging a given linked list in-place:

```
class LinkedList {
    static Node head; // head of the list

    /* Node Class */
    static class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;
        // Constructor to create a new node
        Node(int d)
        {
            data = d;
            next = null;
        }
    }

    void printlist(Node node)
    {
        if (node == null) {
            return;
        }
        while (node != null) {
            System.out.print(node.data + " -> ");
            node = node.next;
        }
    }

    Node reverselist(Node node)
    {
        Node prev = null, curr = node, next;
        while (curr != null) {
            next = curr.next;
            curr.next = prev;
            prev = curr;
            curr = next;
        }
        node = prev;
        return node;
    }

    void rearrange(Node node)
    {
        // 1) Find the middle point using tortoise and hare
        // method
        Node slow = node, fast = slow.next;
        while (fast != null && fast.next != null) {
            slow = slow.next;
            fast = fast.next.next;
        }
        // 2) Split the linked list in two halves
        // node1, head of first half 1 -> 2 -> 3
        // node2, head of second half 4 -> 5
        Node node1 = node;
        Node node2 = slow.next;
        slow.next = null;
        // 3) Reverse the second half, i.e., 5 -> 4
        node2 = reverselist(node2);
        // 4) Merge alternate nodes
        node = new Node(0); // Assign dummy Node
        // curr is the pointer to this dummy Node, which
        // will be used to form the new list
        Node curr=node;
        while (node1 != null || node2 != null) {
            // First add the element from first list
            if (node1 != null) {
                curr.next = node1;
                curr = curr.next;
                node1 = node1.next;
            }
            // Then add the element from second list
            if (node2 != null) {
                curr.next = node2;
                curr = curr.next;
                node2 = node2.next;
            }
        }
        // Assign the head of the new list to head pointer
        node = node.next;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        list.head = new Node(1);
        list.head.next = new Node(2);
        list.head.next.next = new Node(3);
        list.head.next.next.next = new Node(4);
        list.head.next.next.next.next = new Node(5);
        list.head.next.next.next.next.next = new Node(6);
        list.printlist(head); // print original list
        list.rearrange(head); // rearrange list as per ques
        System.out.println("");
        list.printlist(head); // print modified list
    }
}
```

My question is about this section of the code:

```
Node curr=node;
while (node1 != null || node2 != null) {
    // First add the element from first list
    if (node1 != null) {
        curr.next = node1;
        curr = curr.next;
        node1 = node1.next;
    }
    // Then add the element from second list
    if (node2 != null) {
        curr.next = node2;
        curr = curr.next;
        node2 = node2.next;
    }
}
```

I debugged this in VScode, and I see that when `curr` is pointing to `node` the statement `curr.next=node1` creates a change in `node`. But when doing `curr=curr.next` no changes are made to `node`. Why is that happening?

Comment: When working with list it's better to use pointers. Not using them means that `cur=node` makes a copy of  `node`, which is suboptimal for a list. Also you don't pass a pointer to `rearrange` which means all your changes to `node` are lost when the function exits. Perhaps you wnat to return a `Node` type, as you do in `reverselist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `curr` is point to `node` and when `curr.next=node1` it also create change in node but when `curr=curr.next` it does not make any changes in `node`

The only way to make a change to an object, is to assign somehow to *properties* of that object. This is what `curr.next=node1` does: it assigns something to an object's `next` property.

On the other hand, an assignment to a *variable* will never change an object. It merely changes the content of a variable. That is what `curr=curr.next` does.

It may help to visualise it. Let's say we have `node` after the first loop (in a list with just one node)

```
node
 ↓
┌────────────┐
│ data: 1    │ 
│ next: null │ 
└────────────┘
```

Then `Node node1 = node;` creates a new reference to the same node:

```
node  node1
 ↓     ↓
┌────────────┐
│ data: 1    │ 
│ next: null │ 
└────────────┘
```

A bit later, we create a new node with `node = new Node(0);`:

```
node             node1
 ↓                ↓
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ data: 0    │   │ data: 1    │
│ next: null │   │ next: null │ 
└────────────┘   └────────────┘
```

When `Node curr=node;` executes, we merely get a variable that references the same node as `node`:

```
node  curr       node1
 ↓     ↓          ↓
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ data: 0    │   │ data: 1    │
│ next: null │   │ next: null │ 
└────────────┘   └────────────┘
```

When `curr.next=node1` is executed, the `next` property of the object is set to reference the object that `node1` is referencing. So:

```
node  curr       node1
 ↓     ↓          ↓
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ data: 0    │   │ data: 1    │
│ next: ────────►│ next: null │ 
└────────────┘   └────────────┘
```

But when `curr=curr.next` is executed, no object is mutated. This assigns to a *variable*, and that only affects that variable, not what it references:

```
node             curr  node1
 ↓                ↓     ↓
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ data: 0    │   │ data: 1    │
│ next: ────────►│ next: null │ 
└────────────┘   └────────────┘
```

I hope this clarifies the difference.

Comment: Difference between node, curr and node 1?

Comment: All r objects ?

Comment: I am new in programming please help

Comment: These are variables that hold **references** (pointers) to memory locations that have the object properties (in other languages you would say that these variables have pointers to `struct` data). In the diagrams I included you can see the arrows. Variables point to structured data.

Comment: Thanks for ur time.  please clear my confusion that  If any classname is c and  I write c g=new c();

Comment: Then g count as object or reference variable I see that it called object

Comment: In Java objects are always accessed with *references*. Variables are never a kind of `struct` that you have in C. So `new c()` evaluates to a *reference*. The actual data structure (the `struct`) is allocated in memory, but access to that memory always happens with a reference, like when you do with `g.data`.

Comment: Ok, g is reference variable which has object properties of class c

Comment: Yes, please look at the diagrams that I included in my answer. The arrows indicate that the variables do not hold the data structures **in them**, but they hold *references* to them.

Comment: I understand but when I see some articles they told by c g=new c() that they have made a object that's why I am confused

Comment: //Java Program to illustrate how to define a class and fields    
//Defining a Student class.  
class Student {  
 //defining fields  
 int id;.  //field or data member or instance variable  
 String name;  
 //creating main method inside the Student class  
 public static void main(String args[]){  
  //Creating an object or instance  
  Student s1=new Student();//creating an object of Student  
  //Printing values of the object  
  System.out.println(s1.id);//accessing member through reference variable  
  System.out.println(s1.name);  
 }  
}

Comment: Yes, `new`  makes an object. It is just that the created data structure (with all its properties) has been allocated in memory, and `new` returns a reference to that data structure. So it is not wrong to say it "makes an object". But it is equally true to say "and we got a reference to it".

Comment: Ok I understand thank you for your valuable responses